# AWS Code Pipeline - Deploying a React app to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I have a seemingly simple task of trying to deploy a react app to an S3 bucket to use it as a website. I have followed several tutorials and attempted this numerous times and numerous ways. All of them have failed and I am finding this incredibly frustrating and the docs are no help.

Following [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/automate-static-website-deployment-to-amazon-s3.html), I set up a pipeline. I don't need a build, just a deploy that triggers on github push to deploy the built code to the S3 bucket.

I believe that my first problem came at the object key - something which simply isn't in a single AWS doc or example that I could find.

[image]

Do I need to enter the files in the build folder, or the files in the public folder. If I enter an object key of "build/index.html", it pulls those files into the S3 bucket in example that same way, which is obviously not ideal.

I believe that these object keys are the files that the code pipeline is going to pull over - although an explanation of that somewhere would be nice. So, how do I enter the object keys for a react app?

I also tried uploading the files manually to the S3 bucket and using that as a website, but it simply downloaded the files instead of running the code and viewing it as a website.

Comment: Yes, s3 is only a storage service, it won't run code. You need to deploy on an ec2 instance.

Comment: S3 will host static websites. It hosted the site just fine for a while before I tried to implement a code pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Check `"Extract file before deploy"` then you can skip `Deployment path` as empty if you want to deploy your files in root directory.
When check `"Extract file before deploy"` `S3 bucket Key` field will be disappeared.